# Is the port 443 required when setting cookie exceptions on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, https, cookies

In my Chrome cookie exceptions I have a lot of `https://` entries. Some have a trailing `:443`, some others don't.

As `443` is the default HTTPS port, is it required in the exception? Would `https://example.com` differ from `https://example.com:443`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `HTTPS`, Port 443 is implied. You can see this by attempting to visit a site such as `https://www.google.com:443` - the 443 will be removed by Google Chrome. As such, you shouldn't require it when specifying exceptions unless it runs on a different port.